# Printing negative numbers created on the fly gives incorrect output in c++

Tags: c++

Following code explains a quirk, and I am unable to understand why it is the way it is. The comments in the code explain the quirk:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string a,b;
    a = "abc";
    b = "def";
    // On the fly calculation of diff does not lead to desirable results.
    cout<<"a size: "<<a.size()<<" b size: "<<b.size()<<" diff: "<<a.size()-b.size()-1<<endl;
    // Following assignment works as expected.
    int diff = a.size()-b.size()-1;
    cout<<"diff "<<diff<<endl;
    for (int i=a.size()-1; i>a.size()-b.size()-1; --i) {
        cout<<"running"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output I get:

```
a size: 3 b size: 3 diff: 4294967295
diff: -1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a.size()-b.size()-1
```

Since the `size` method returns a `size_t`, i.e. an unsigned value, you're computing `3-3-1 = -1` in an "unsigned space" which gives you a wrong value.

Try:

```
int(a.size())-int(b.size())-1
```

Comment: I was expecting something of that sort, but didn't think return type to be a problem. makes sense.